# How to set a UIBarButtonItem backgroundImage for all possible states?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

Right now I am writing this to set the background image of a UIBarButtonItem:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateHighlighted barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateDisabled barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

How can I DRY this up?

Thanks,
Nicolas

Comment: ```for state: UIControl.State in [.application, .disabled, .focused, .highlighted, .normal, .reserved, .selected] {
                                    myButton.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: 40], for: state)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really enumerate the values of an `enum` in any particularly convenient way in C; the best you can do is stick the values you care about into an array and iterate that.

```
NSUInteger controlStates[] = {UIControlStateNormal, UIControlStateHighlighted, UIControlStateSelected, UIControlStateDisabled};
NSUInteger numControlStates = 4;
for( NSUInteger i = 0; i < numControlStates; i++ ){
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:image 
                                            forState:controlStates[i]
                                          barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Taken from the UIBarButtonItem docs:

> In general, you should specify a value for the normal state to be used by other states which don’t have a custom value set. Similarly, when a property is dependent on the bar metrics (on iPhone, in landscape orientation bars have a different height from standard), you should specify a value of UIBarMetricsDefault.

Basically, you only need to set the value for UIControlStateNormal unless you are setting custom values for the others. If you aren't setting custom values, they will default to the value you set for UIControlStateNormal.

Comment: It seems that when I do that, some default values would take precedence over what I set for the UIControlStateNormal. For example, if I apply the setTitleTextAttributes method to have the word "Back" in green in the button only for UIControlStateNormal, then it would turn to white when I click on it instead of staying green. So although I changed the UIControlStateNormal value, it doesn't seem to affect the other states as I expected.

Answer (score 0):

BarButtonItems use the background image set for the Normal state unless you specifically set the image for another state so you could just write

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

If you want to be more explicit you could also just OR all the states together (they are bitwise flags)

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal | UIControlStateHighlighted | UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateDisabled barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: I just tried the explicit version and it doesn't work for me here. Specifically, I tried this:
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal | UIControlStateHighlighted | UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

The background image remains the default blue array instead of my new image.

Comment: Just be aware that setBackButtonBackgroundImage (which you used here but not in your original question) only applies to UIBarButtonItems that are Back buttons.  I just want to make sure you're not getting things confused between two similar looking methods.

Comment: Thanks. I know the difference, I am actually using both in my code, and I played with setBackButtonBackgroundImage so I could easily see if the functionality would work with the different states and it didn't with the OR operator.

Comment: The fact that the values can be combined in one call because the argument's type is a set of flags doesn't mean that the method will actually _use_ all the values; the singular `forState:` strongly suggests that it won't.